# Why is my website when using www inaccessible? asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sitecore8

If I access : `https://example.com`, it works. The website can be accessed

But if I access : `https://www.example.com`, it can't be accessed like this :

[image: error page]

Do I need settings in web.config?

Comment: is your dns configured/cache cleared?

Comment: Three hints to get you started: D, N, and S.

Comment: It's either DNS, or your web site is not configured to respond to the host name www.whatever. Either way, it's nothing to do with your web.config.

Comment: @Gabriel Luci  Okay. How can I setting it? My website is stored on the portal azure. Can I set it on the portal azure?

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn  My website is stored on the portal azure. Can I set dns on the portal azure?

Comment: @Daniel A. White Where can I see that?

Comment: @SuccessMan consult with the documentation of your hosting provider

Comment: @Daniel A. White My website is stored on the portal azure. So I set it on the portal azure?

Comment: @Daniel A. White Is it like this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain

Comment: @SuccessMan This is DNS issue. Have you tested to ping your domain? Has it resolved to correct IP address?

Comment: @Mark Spence How can I tested to ping in portal azure?

Comment: @SuccessMan Not on portal azure. Please read https://smallbusiness.chron.com/ping-website-cmd-53939.html#:~:text=Within%20the%20prompt%2C%20type%20%22cmd,press%20the%20%22enter%22%20key. You can open your cmd and then ping your domain, please check whether your domain has pointed to correct IP address or not.

Answer (score 0):

add domain`www.example.com` to Azure. See the details below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/add-custom-domain

Comment: My website is deployed not in Azure, but I met this problem before.  For www.example.com, the browser is inaccessible because the domain name configuration item is not mapped and the DNS service does not know its corresponding IP address.

Comment: I try to added a custom domain in portal azure and click validate and it appears that way. Next I was confused to set up. Do I need to run next? https://ibb.co/c18s2xh

Comment: It seems you are not using a real domain owned but azurewebsite.com. I'm sorry you could not get what you want in this domain because you can only use second domain like XXX.azurewebsites.net.

Comment: This is domain for staging website. So I can't add that? Maybe I should try on production website directly

Comment: After I check my production, it turns out it has worked because it's been set up like this : https://ibb.co/bHHQWcP. This problem only occurs on server staging

Comment: That's right, you have no privilege to add www.xxx.com domain for your staging server. But you can use www-example-com.azurewebsites.net domain name.

Comment: Actually I need to add `www` in my staging server for testing. I want to test when a user accesses a domain without www, it will redirect to www. But no problem. I will try it in my production server